# Codewars Kata: Converting snake_case identifiers to CamelCase in C++

Tags: c++

I did this kata from codewars:

> Complete the method/function so that it converts dash/underscore delimited words into camel casing. The first word within the output should be capitalized only if the original word was capitalized (known as Upper Camel Case, also often referred to as Pascal case).
>
> Examples:
> "the-stealth-warrior" gets converted to "theStealthWarrior"
> "The_Stealth_Warrior" gets converted to "TheStealthWarrior"

I went through the answers after submitting my piece and all of them look longer than mine in code, and I wonder if they are more efficient.

```
std::string to_camel_case(std::string text) {
  for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); it++)
  {
      if (*it == '-' || *it == '_')
      {
        it = text.erase(it);
        *it = toupper(*it);
      }
  }
  return text;
}
```

It matches the outputs. Is there anything wrong with what I did when it comes to C++ standards or good practice? In which ways could this code be improved?

Comment: What if there is a `-` or `_` at the end of the string, or before a space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unnecessarily slow in at least a couple of different ways.

1. Your algorithm is O(N²), but there are easy O(N) algorithms.
2. You copy the input string unnecessarily. You could easily pass it by reference.

It's O(N²) because easy time you encounter a `-` or `_`, you copy the entire rest of the string to delete that one element. You can (for one example) just keep track of a "source" position and a "destination" position, copying elements from source to destination, skipping the ones you don't want, and capitalizing as needed. Then when you've copied all you need, you can eliminate all the ones you no longer need at once (all from the end, so you don't need to copy others after them).

Comment: He's passing the string by value because he changes it and returns the changed version.  Passing by reference would also mean changing the function to modify the original in place, which is a different definition.  Since the string is copied anyway (anything after the first snake must be copied) I don't think that would save much, unless you expect a lot of strings that don't need any change.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [Jerry's answer](/a/263750), you have:

```
std::string to_camel_case(std::string text) {
  for (auto it = text.begin(); it != text.end(); it++)
  {
      if (*it == '-' || *it == '_')
      {
        it = text.erase(it);    // This line has a hidden loop.
                                // You are basically looping over
                                // the whole string and moving all
                                // the characters down one place.
        *it = toupper(*it);
      }
  }
  return text;
}
```

You want to re-write this removing the extra loop:

```
std::string to_camel_case(std::string text) {

  static const std::function<char(unsigned char)> converter[2] = {
      [](unsigned char x){return x;},
      [](unsigned char x){return std::toupper(x);}
  };

  std::size_t removedChars = 0;
  bool        convert      = false;
  for (auto loop = 0u; loop < text.size(); ++loop)
  {
      if (text[loop] == '-' || text[loop] == '_')
      {
        ++removedChars;
        convert = true;
        continue;
      }
      text[loop - removedChars] = converter[convert](text[loop]);
      convert = false;
  }
  text.resize(text.size() - removedChars);
  return text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single pass, resulting in an \$O(n)\$ algorithm instead of your current \$O(n²)\$ algorithm. The idea is to process the input in order, immediately adding to the output as appropriate.

There is a reason to accept the argument by value, and that is avoiding allocations. If an allocation is needed, the caller can do it.

Currently, you pass a raw `char` to `std::toupper()`. Unfortunately, that function expects the value of an `unsigned char` or `EOF` (which is `-1`) passed as an `int`. Anything out of range causes *Undefined Behavior*.

Using manual iterator-handling when a range-based `for` loop fits is cumbersome and error-prone.

Currently, if you have an even number of `-` and `_` following each other, you miss out on upper-casing the following character.

Also, if the string ends with an odd number of `-` and `_`, you mistakenly append a `'\0'`.

```
constexpr std::string to_camel_case(std::string s) noexcept {
    bool tail = false;
    std::size_t n = 0;
    for (unsigned char c : s) {
        if (c == '-' || c == '_') {
            tail = false;
        } else if (tail) {
            s[n++] = c;
        } else {
            tail = true;
            s[n++] = std::toupper(c);
        }
    }
    s.resize(n);
    return s;
}
```